# get the class of "case class" from it's companion

Tags: scala, types

I have the following code:

```scala
trait Base[A,B] {
  def name: String
}

trait BaseCompanion[A,B] {
  def classOfBase: Class[_ <: Base[A,B]]   // Can I implement something generic here ?
}

case class First(name: String) extends Base[Int,String]

object First extends BaseCompanion[Int,String] {
  override def classOfBase: Class[_ <: Base[Int, String]] = classOf[First] // Can this part be generic ?
}
```

I don't want to override the `classOfBase` method in every concrete class that will extend `BaseCompanion`.This can be achieved by changing `BaseCompanion` to:

```scala
abstract class BaseCompanion[A,B, CLAZZ <: Base[A,B] : ClassTag] {
  def classOfBase: Class[CLAZZ] = classTag[CLAZZ].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[CLAZZ]]
}

object First extends BaseCompanion[Int,String,First]
```

But I don't really like this solution, is there a way to do this without changing the signature of `BaseCompanion` and implement something generic inside the it ?

By the way today Companion object of any case class "defines" `apply(...)` method. Given the example above there will be a method similar to this:

```
abstract class BaseCompanion[A,B, CLAZZ <: Base[A,B] : ClassTag] {
  def classOfBase: Class[CLAZZ] = classTag[CLAZZ].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[CLAZZ]]
  /* No need to implement in the companion of a case class that extends Base */
  def apply(name: String): Base[A,B] 
}
```

The return type of this `apply` method is known to the Companion perhaps there is a way to use this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done with this change:

```
def classOfBase = this.getClass.getMethods.find(_.getName == "apply").get.
  getReturnType.asInstanceOf[Class[_ <: Base[A,B]]]
```

Note that this assumes there is precisely one `apply` method. In practice, you should check this assumption.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey Romanov, that's an excellent idea. I think I will mark it with an annotation and check with 'isAnnotationPresent' this way it will compile safe and I can make different `apply` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that if what you want would work, the following would be possible:

```
case class First(name: String) extends Base[Int, String]
object First extends BaseCompanion[Int, String]

assert(First.baseClass == classOf[First])
```

Now *if* that would work, what would stop you from doing the following?

```
class Second extends BaseCompanion[Int, String]
val second = new Second

println(second.baseClass)
```

or

```
// case class Third not defined
object Third extends BaseCompanion[Int, String]

println(Third.baseClass)
```

What would that result in? `Second` and `Third` are not a companion object with an associated class. `Second` is a class itself!

The problem is that you cannot force your `BaseCompanion` trait to only be inherited by something that is a companion object. `BaseCompanion` therefore cannot use the special relation that companion objects and associated classes have. If you want information about the associated class with a companion object, you have to give `BaseCompanion` that information *manually* in the definition of your companion object.

The Scala compiler won't allow you to do this. You can work around this with reflection if you want, but whatever solution remains that accomplishes this has to take into account that you are effectively creating unpredictable runtime behaviour. In my opinion, it's best to just help the compiler figure it out, and supply the proper information at compile time.

Comment: Well actually I can "enforce" to some degree that my `BaseCompanion` will be inherited by a Companion Object. I can achieve this by defining an abstract method to be automatically implemented by the compiler.
`def apply(name: String): Base[A,B]`

This is not perfect but with a proper guiding it can be enforced.

Comment: @TalG. I'm not sure I completely follow. You are talking about "enforcing" by code style rules instead of the compiler enforcing it, I take it?